# How the delegates objects are created in c#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I just started learning delegates in c#. How the delegate object is created when the compiler encounter the following code

```
 delegate int Transformer (int x);
 Transformer t = new Transformer (Square);
```

I found that all the delegates implicitly derives the System.Delegate class. Will the "new Transformer (Square)" call the constructor of the Delegate class to create the object called 't'.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back on Roslyn Reference Sources for .net framework 4.6.2 The System.Delegate class constructor looks like the following:

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
        protected Delegate(Object target,String method)
        {
            if (target == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
            Contract.EndContractBlock();

            // This API existed in v1/v1.1 and only expected to create closed
            // instance delegates. Constrain the call to BindToMethodName to
            // such and don't allow relaxed signature matching (which could make
            // the choice of target method ambiguous) for backwards
            // compatibility. The name matching was case sensitive and we
            // preserve that as well.
            if (!BindToMethodName(target, (RuntimeType)target.GetType(), method,
                                  DelegateBindingFlags.InstanceMethodOnly |
                                  DelegateBindingFlags.ClosedDelegateOnly))
                throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_DlgtTargMeth"));
        }

        // This constructor is called from a class to generate a 
        // delegate based upon a static method name and the Type object
        // for the class defining the method.
        [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
        protected unsafe Delegate(Type target,String method)
        {
            if (target == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

            if (target.IsGenericType && target.ContainsGenericParameters)
                throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_UnboundGenParam"), "target");

            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
            Contract.EndContractBlock();

            RuntimeType rtTarget = target as RuntimeType;
            if (rtTarget == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_MustBeRuntimeType"), "target");

            // This API existed in v1/v1.1 and only expected to create open
            // static delegates. Constrain the call to BindToMethodName to such
            // and don't allow relaxed signature matching (which could make the
            // choice of target method ambiguous) for backwards compatibility.
            // The name matching was case insensitive (no idea why this is
            // different from the constructor above) and we preserve that as
            // well.
            BindToMethodName(null, rtTarget, method,
                             DelegateBindingFlags.StaticMethodOnly |
                             DelegateBindingFlags.OpenDelegateOnly |
                             DelegateBindingFlags.CaselessMatching);
        }
```

So, yeah you can expect a derived type from this guy there.

If you're looking for basics on delegates: (I think I misread the question, still keeping it here)

Syntax for delegate declaration is

```
delegate <return type> <delegate-name> <parameter list>
```

[From MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type. When you instantiate a delegate, you can associate its instance with any method with a compatible signature and return type. You can invoke (or call) the method through the delegate instance.

So, once a delegate type is declared, a delegate object must be created with the new keyword and be associated with a particular method. When creating a delegate, the argument passed to the new expression is written similar to a method call, but without the arguments to the method.

```
public delegate void printStuff(string s);
...
printStuff ps1 = new printStuff(WriteToScreen);
printStuff ps2 = new printStuff(WriteToScreen);
```

`WriteToScreen` and `WriteToScreen` here are actually methods with a string in params.